# Certain Nginx configurations are causing failure to start Nginx

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

When I try to enable either one the following settings, Nginx fails to start.

```
gzip_vary on;
gzip_comp_level 6;
```

Nginx gives me the following error.

```
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

`systemctl status nginx.service` gives me the following output.

```
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2016-12-26 16:05:32 UTC; 8s ago
Docs: man:nginx(8)
Process: 9504 ExecStop=/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry QUIT/5 --pidfile /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 9481 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

I am using Nginx version 1.11.5 on Ubuntu 16.04

Edit: `nginx -V` output:

```
nginx version: nginx/1.11.5
built with OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now' --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-debug --with-pcre-jit --with-ipv6 --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_slice_module --with-threads --with-http_addition_module --with-http_geoip_module=dynamic --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module=dynamic --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module=dynamic --with-stream=dynamic --with-stream_ssl_module --with-mail=dynamic --with-mail_ssl_module --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-Rrk92d/nginx-1.11.5/debian/modules/nginx-auth-pam --add-module=/build/nginx-Rrk92d/nginx-1.11.5/debian/modules/nginx-dav-ext-module --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-Rrk92d/nginx-1.11.5/debian/modules/nginx-echo --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-Rrk92d/nginx-1.11.5/debian/modules/nginx-upstream-fair --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-Rrk92d/nginx-1.11.5/debian/modules/ngx_http_substitutions_filter_module
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the output of the command "nginx -V".

Comment: @Tim I've edited my question.

Answer (score 2):

Those two commands are in the module ngx_http_gzip_module, which isn't compiled into your version of Nginx. You'll need to get a different version or build it from source.

I have a [tutorial on building from source](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-part-2-setting-up-aws-for-wordpress-with-rds-nginx-hhvm-php-ssmtp/#nginx-source) here for Amazon Linux / Centos, it's quite easy. The key parts are below. I've removed parts for cache purge and Google Pagespeed. Since you're on Ubuntu you'll be using apt-get instead of yum, you may need to find a different tutorial if you can't work the details out, like this one from [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04), just make sure you include the module I pointed out, and the headers one is useful too.

```
cd /home/ec2-user
mkdir nginx-build
cd nginx-build
service nginx stop
yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
yum install pcre-devel zlib-devel openssl-devel
wget http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.11.4.tar.gz # Update to the latest availble
wget https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module/archive/v0.31.tar.gz
tar -xzf nginx-1.9.11.tar.gz
tar -xzf v0.31.tar.gz

cd nginx-1.11.4
# Note that I have no idea what the next line does but it was in the official guide
PS_NGX_EXTRA_FLAGS="--with-cc=/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/bin/gcc"
# Safe option, slower, lots of modules included
#./configure --prefix=/etc/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/client_temp --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/scgi_temp --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-threads --with-stream --with-stream_ssl_module --with-http_slice_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-file-aio --with-ipv6 --with-http_v2_module --with-cc-opt='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic' --add-module=/tmp/headers-more-nginx-module-0.29 --with-http_realip_module 
# Many plugins removed, extra optimisations including some JUST for the machine it's compiled on
./configure --prefix=/etc/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/client_temp --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/scgi_temp --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-threads --with-file-aio --with-ipv6 --with-http_v2_module --with-cc-opt='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=native' --add-module=../headers-more-nginx-module-0.31 --with-http_realip_module
make && make install
make clean  (NB: optional)
service nginx start
```

Comment: Should I uninstall all nginx-related packages first? I have `nginx`, `nginx-common`, `nginx-full` and a bunch of `libnginx-mod-x` installed with apt-get.

Comment: I don't know for sure. Take a backup, try with just the compiled Nginx, if that doesn't work try removing all that and installing with/after Nginx.